# Python Tkinter - Get value from mutliple checkboxes

Tags: python-2.7, variables, for-loop, checkbox, tkinter

I am creating a Tkinter application where trying to get value from multiple checkboxes. I am able to create the checkboxes but not able to retrieve the value .i.e. checked or not checked checkboxes.

**Requirement:**

I need to loop through all checkbox variables to identify the checked ones.

```
import openpyxl
import sys
import pandas as pd
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkFont


reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

top = Tk()
notebook = ttk.Notebook(top)
notebook.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky=W)
frame1 = ttk.Frame(top)
notebook.add(frame1, text='TAB1')
s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('clam')
helv36 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight=tkFont.BOLD)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('File',data_only=True)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

mylist = []
mylist1 = []
for col in ws['A']:
     mylist.append(col.value)
for col in ws['B']:
    mylist1.append(col.value)

mylist = [str(item) for item in mylist]
mylist1 = [str(item) for item in mylist1]

i=2
for name in mylist:
    Label(frame1, text="col1",
          borderwidth=1,font=helv36).grid(row=1)
    Label(frame1, text=name,
                  borderwidth=1).grid(row=i)
    i +=1


i =2
for name in mylist1:
    Label(frame1, text="col2",
          borderwidth=1,font=helv36).grid(row=1, column=1)
    Label(frame1, text=name,
          borderwidth=1).grid(row=i,column=1)
    val = IntVar()
    val = "v" + str(i)
    c_val = Checkbutton(frame1, variable=val)
    c_val.grid(row=i, column=2,sticky = W)
    i +=1


***def chkbox_checked():
    #Need to loop to get checked checkboxes***


B200 = Button(frame1, text ="Check", command = chkbox_checked,font=helv36, bg='orange')
B200.grid(row=100)
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've given a requirement but haven't asked a question. What part of the solution do you need help with?

Comment: I need to get variables of Checkboxes which are checked

Answer (score 1):

You can associate a BooleanVar to the checkbox and get the value. You can then use set() method to set the default value for the checkbox and get() to get the state of the checkbox. For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
c=tk.BooleanVar()
tk.Checkbutton(root,variable=c,command=lambda: print(c.get())).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

if you want to loop over a number of checkboxes, you can do this:

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()

c1=tk.BooleanVar()
c2=tk.BooleanVar()
c3=tk.BooleanVar()
c4=tk.BooleanVar()

def get_value():
    for c in (c1,c2,c3,c4):
        print(c.get())

tk.Checkbutton(root,text='checkbox1',variable=c1,).pack()
tk.Checkbutton(root,text='checkbox2',variable=c2,).pack()
tk.Checkbutton(root,text='checkbox3',variable=c3,).pack()
tk.Checkbutton(root,text='checkbox4',variable=c4,).pack()
tk.Button(root,text='get value',command=get_value).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ok I have loop over dynamically because I don't know how many checkbox will be created It may vary at different conditions. Can you help me with that    @Mia